# Xcode Variable has incomplete type void

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, objective-c++

I am working on a cross platform c++ app. On the mac version I need to use a little bit of cocoa in obj-c. So I have made a class called OSXSpecifics and it has the .mm file extension and a c++ header like the rest of the app.

```
std::string OSXSpecifics::GetOSXFilePath(const char *name, const char *type) {
return [[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithUTF8String: name]
                                        ofType:[NSString stringWithUTF8String: type]] UTF8String];

}
```

The above code works absolutely perfect. A c++ function in a c++ class with objective-c inside the function. But when I do this:

```
void OSXSpecifics::printToConsole(<#const char *text#>) {
NSString *Text = [NSString stringWithUTF8String: text];

}
```

I get a couple of errors. Mainly: `variable has incomplete type 'void`. I also get `expected primary expression before '<'token`. And also of interest: `expected ';' after top level declarator`.
This is the header file for the class:

```
#ifndef OSXSPECIFICS_h
#define OSXSPECIFICS_h

#include <string.h>

class OSXSpecifics
{
public:
    static std::string GetOSXFilePath(const char* name, const char* type);
    static void printToConsole(const char* text);
};

#endif // OSXSPECIFICS_h
```

Any idea's why xcode is freaking out about c++ and objective c mixing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `<#const char *text#>` should be `const char *text`.

The `<#` and `#>` were put there by Xcode's autocomplete system and should be removed.

Comment: wow, thanks, I feel stupid but they didn't even show up in xcode